# Faker() raised Django ImproperlyConfigured Error

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

trying to run some fake data using Faker but been trying for 2 days now to solve and i cant. i need a little help here would be much appreciated below is the code and the error.I've tried multiple way to try an access Django's setting module but its not working i believe problem is in line 10 os.eniron....etc

im working on Windows 10, Sqlite, python 3.8.2 and django 3 and venv enviroment python -m venv name

i have the django admin on already i do not know what would be the problem now...
any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

test_first_app.py

```
import django
import os
import random

from faker import Faker

from first_app.models import AccessRecord, WebPage, Topic


os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_project.settings')
django.setup()

fake = Faker

topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t


def populate(n=5):
    for entry in range(n):
        top = add_topic()
        fake_url = fake.url()
        fake_date = fake.date()
        fake_name = fake.company()

        webpge = WebPage.objects.get_or_create(topic=top, url=fake_url, name=fake_name)[0]
        fkacc = AccessRecord.objects.get_create(name=webpge, date=fake_date)[0] # for some reason pycharm saying this variable is not used


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating script")
    populate(20)
    print("Done!!")
```

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class Topic(models.Model):
    top_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.top_name


class WebPage(models.Model):
    topic = models.ForeignKey(Topic, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, unique=True)
    url = models.URLField(unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class AccessRecord(models.Model):
    name = models.ForeignKey(WebPage, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.date)
```

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for first_project project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 3.0.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/
"""

import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '-2gjsys0wt$&8sod%662o$=@2&s)+n_*8o$l)5=i3t#f(af+2y'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'first_app',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'first_project.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'first_project.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
    '/Django-Udemy/udemy/static/',
]
```

Error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_first_app.py", line 7, in <module>
    from first_app.models import AccessRecord, WebPage, Topic
  File "D:\OneDrive\School\Django-Udemy\udemy\first_app\models.py", line
4, in <module>
    class Topic(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pac
kages\django\db\models\base.py", line 107, in __new__
    app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pac
kages\django\apps\registry.py", line 252, in get_containing_app_config
    self.check_apps_ready()
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pac
kages\django\apps\registry.py", line 134, in check_apps_ready
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pac
kages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 76, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "C:\Users\T\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\lib\site-pac
kages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 57, in _setup
raise ImproperlyConfigured(
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting INSTALLED_APPS,
but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable
e DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings
.
```

Answer (score 1):

I saw several problem with the code above:

1. You haven't instantiated Faker

```
from faker import Faker
fake = Faker()
```

2. I think you tried to access django outside django apps. If my guess is correct you tried to populate some random data. For this purpose I think you can do it using django custom command :
   https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

I just debug my populate.py file and found that i was importing the models.py before configuring Django so first you need to set environment then you need to setup django and at last you can import models in populate.py file.

```
from faker import Faker
import random
import django
import os

# Configure settings for project
# Need to run this before calling models from application!
os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'first_model.settings') # this should be done first.

# Import settings
django.setup() # This needs to be done after you set the environ

from first_app.models import Topic, WebPage, AccessRecord # At last you can import models in populate.py file
# Now you are good to go for running this file

fakegen = Faker()
topics = ['Search', 'Social', 'Marketplace', 'News', 'Games']


def add_topic():
    t = Topic.objects.get_or_create(top_name=random.choice(topics))[0]
    t.save()
    return t


def populate(N=5):
    '''
    Create N Entries of Dates Accessed
    '''

    for entry in range(N):

        # Get Topic for Entry
        top = add_topic()

        # Create Fake Data for entry
        fake_url = fakegen.url()
        fake_date = fakegen.date()
        fake_name = fakegen.company()

        # Create new Webpage Entry
        webpg = WebPage.objects.get_or_create(
            topic=top, name=fake_name, url=fake_url,)[0]

        # Create Fake Access Record for that page
        # Could add more of these if you wanted...
        accRec = AccessRecord.objects.get_or_create(
            name=webpg, date=fake_date)[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print("Populating the databases...Please Wait")
    populate(20)
    print('Populating Complete')
```